# Android: what dependencies to import for Futures and AppSearch Android 12

Tags: android, concurrent.futures, android-12, app-search

I'm following this tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/appsearch#groovy
to make a sample app using AppSearch. However, when I get the schema part, I have unknown references on "Futures". I tried to look for any dependencies related to Futures concurrent for Android and I found 3 dependencies but it's not solving the unknown references to "Futures". I also don't know what should be "mExecutor" because I can't see the "Futures" class and its function because of the unknown reference.

Here is my my dependencies:

```
def appsearch_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-listenablefuture-callback:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-listenablefuture:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures-ktx:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.appsearch:appsearch:$appsearch_version"
    // Use kapt instead of annotationProcessor if writing Kotlin classes
    annotationProcessor "androidx.appsearch:appsearch-compiler:$appsearch_version"

    implementation "androidx.appsearch:appsearch-local-storage:$appsearch_version"
    // PlatformStorage is compatible with Android 12+ devices, and offers additional features
    // to LocalStorage.
    implementation "androidx.appsearch:appsearch-platform-storage:$appsearch_version"
```

Here is my code (the exact same as in the developer guide):

```
    val sessionFuture = LocalStorage.createSearchSession(
                LocalStorage.SearchContext.Builder(this, /*databaseName=*/"notes_app")
                    .build()
            )
            val setSchemaRequest = SetSchemaRequest.Builder().addDocumentClasses(Note::class.java)
                .build()
            val setSchemaFuture = Futures.transformAsync(//Futures unknown reference
                sessionFuture,
                { session ->
                    session?.setSchema(setSchemaRequest)
                }, mExecutor//?
            )

val putRequest = PutDocumentsRequest.Builder().addDocuments(note).build()
            val putFuture = Futures.transformAsync(
                sessionFuture,
                { session ->
                    session?.put(putRequest)
                }, mExecutor
            )
            Futures.addCallback(//Futures unknown reference
                putFuture,
                object : FutureCallback<AppSearchBatchResult<String, Void>?{//FutureCallback unknown reference
                    override fun onSuccess(result: AppSearchBatchResult<String, Void>?) {

                        // Gets map of successful results from Id to Void
                        val successfulResults = result?.successes

                        // Gets map of failed results from Id to AppSearchResult
                        val failedResults = result?.failures
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to put documents.", t)
                    }
                },
                mExecutor//?
            )
```

If you have any idea of the import I need to implement or any way to achieve the same thing with the kotlin coroutine ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late for the answer. But, just in case if someone else is still searching for it, you will have to use Guava dependency

```
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).